# Fade top of image with shape

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, shapes

I want to fade top of my image with its background.
with this code I can fade right of image how to fade top of image?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Add an `angle` attribute. [The docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) explain this.

Answer (score 1):

Use angle attr to control the direction of shape from top to bottom.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#00FFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```